# Array variable initialization error in Java

Tags: java, initialization

I am trying to write a Java program that reads an input file consisting of URLs, extracts tokens from these, and keeps track of how many times each token appears in the file. I've written the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Main {

    static class Tokens
    {
        String name;
        int count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url_str,host;
        String htokens[];
        URL url;
        boolean found=false;
        Tokens t[];
        int i,j,k;

        try
        {
            File f=new File("urlfile.txt");
            FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

            while((url_str=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                url=new URL(url_str);
                host=url.getHost();
                htokens=host.split("\\.|\\-|\\_|\\~|[0-9]");

                for(i=0;i<htokens.length;i++)
                {
                    if(!htokens[i].isEmpty()) 
                    {
                        for(j=0;j<t.length;j++)
                        {
                            if(htokens[i].equals(t[j].name))
                            {   t[j].count++;  found=true;    }
                        }
                        if(!found)
                        {
                            k=t.length;
                            t[k].name=htokens[i];
                            t[k].count=1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(t.length + "class tokens :");
                for(i=0;i<t.length;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(
                            "name :"+t[i].name+" frequency :"+t[i].count);
                }
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run it, it says: `variable t not initialized.`. What should I do to set it right?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should `break` out of the inner loop when you set `found = true`. And a `HashMap<String, Integer>` will provide much, much better performance if you have a large number of tokens, so consider that too.

Comment: Another note, sometimes with test code like this where you are doing a try/catch(Exception) to avoid a bunch of exceptions, I prefer to just have my main throw Exception--that's a way I identify "Test/experimental" code.  In shipping code, however, never catch Exception, list the ones you actually expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in Java are *fixed length*, so I think what you really want to do is use a `List<Tokens>`

e.g.

```
List<Tokens> t = new ArrayList<Tokens>();
```

and

```
t.add(new Tokens(...))
```

unless you know in advance the number of items you'll have.

Comment: Thank you so much , i wanted a dynamic array , and this worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize it:

```
// Declaration:
Tokens[] t;

// Initialization:
t = new Tokens[10]; // (Or whatever your desired length is)
```

You *can* combine declaration and initialization, and many do. I'm not a fan of doing so, but:

```
Tokens[] t = new Tokens[10];
```

You'll have the same issue with `htokens`.

You may want to look at the [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface (and its various implementations) instead of using an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing `Tokens t[];` before using it.

**EDIT** : You need to it as below :

```
Tokens[] t = new Tokens[100];   //  100 is just an example
```

Or use `List<Tokens>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code declares that t will represent an array of Tokens.

However, it does not define that array.

Per the [Java Documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), you need a line like:

```
t = new Tokens[10]; // Or however large the array should be
```

Answer (score 0):

The modified code : < as per Brian Agnew's answer >

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {


      static class Tokens
        {
            String name;
            int count;
            Tokens(String str,int c)
            {
                name=str;
                count=c;
            }
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url_str,host;
        String htokens[];
        URL url;
        boolean found=false;
        List<Tokens> t = new ArrayList<Tokens>();

        int i,j,k;

        try
        {
            File f=new File("urlfile.txt");
            FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);


          while((url_str=br.readLine())!=null)
          {
          url=new URL(url_str);

          host=url.getHost();
          htokens=host.split("\\.|\\-|\\_|\\~|[0-9]");

            for(i=0;i<htokens.length;i++)
            {
                if(!htokens[i].isEmpty()) 
                {
                    found=false;
                    for(j=0;j<t.size();j++)
                    {

                        if(htokens[i].equals(t.get(j).name))
                        {
                            k=t.get(j).count+1;
                            t.set(j,new Tokens(htokens[i],k));
                            found=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!found)
                    {
                        t.add(new Tokens(htokens[i],1));
                    }
                }
            }

          }
          System.out.println(t.size() + "class tokens :");
          for(i=0;i<t.size();i++)
          {
              System.out.println("name :"+t.get(i).name+" freq :"+t.get(i).count);
          }
          br.close();
          fr.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention, you should not use C-like array syntax, i.e. use

```
String[] names = { "Walter", "Hans", "Bill" };
```

Instead of

```
String names[] = { "Walter", "Hans", "Bill" };
```